# Obtener texto de base de datos ignorando las etiquetas

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Buenas,

Tengo en una base de datos unos artículos guardados, donde aparecen todas las etiquetas para que al volcarlo con PHP pueda carga todos los elementos ,,

...

El caso es que un la previsualización del artículo sólo quiero que sea vea texto plano. He probado con 2 opciones pero ninguna me da el resultado que quiero:

```
echo "<p>" . htmlspecialchars(substr($articulos[$i]['articulo'], 0, 300)) . "...</p>";
```

En este caso me devuelve todo el texto de la base de datos con las etiquetas, sin convertir el texto a código HTML.

```
echo "<p>" . substr($articulos[$i]['articulo'], 0, 300) . "...</p>";
```

En este otro caso convierte las etiquetas HTML, pero si hay etiquetas  al principio del artículo aparecen y me desvirtúa todo...

Lo único que se me ocurre es que los primeros 300 caracteres de los artículos sean texto con la etiqueta

, pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de salvar éste problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que necesitas es **strip_tags()**.
Esta función elimina las etiquetas HTML y PHP de un texto, también admite parámetros para eliminar todas las etiquetas salvo algunas en concreto.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: ¡En el clavo! Muchas gracias, solucionado pues el problema.